# Incorrect number format (.0115 instead of 0.115) after the cursor execution

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I try to execute this code, but get incorrect type of numbers in the output.I've tried to change (precision, scale) for source table change NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS but no results.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
--Declare variables
  v_pr number ;
  v_fin number ;
--Declare cursor 
CURSOR cur_price IS
  SELECT price FROM prices;
BEGIN
OPEN cur_price; 
LOOP      --Simple Loop Start
  FETCH cur_price INTO v_pr; 
  v_fin := v_pr * 1.15; --Calculation
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (to_char(v_pr) ||' --> '|| to_char(v_fin));  --Show the result
  EXIT WHEN cur_price%NOTFOUND; 
END LOOP; --Simple Loop End
CLOSE cur_price;
END;
-----------------
.01 --> .0115
.02 --> .023
.03 --> .0345
.03 --> .0345
```

Table parameters:

```
select * from prices
----------------
0.01
0.02
0.03


desc prices
Name  Null? Type        
----- ----- ----------- 
PRICE       NUMBER(6,3)
```

NLS parameters:

```
select value
from nls_session_parameters
where parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS';

VALUE
-------------------------------
.,
```

Comment: `0.01 * 1.15` equals `0.0115`, not `0.115`.

Comment: Is that a typo? Do you mean, the output you wanted is 0.0115? You wrote 0.115, which - as Ponder Stibbons points out correctly - is not the correct answer for your calculation, regardless of format. If in fact your question is how to get the correct answer, but in the format 0.0115: I see you already marked a Correct Answer, which does **not** tell you, though, how to do that. So, do you know how? Or do you still need help with that? (And if you do, how is the answer you marked as "correct" the correct answer to your question?)

Comment: @mathguy Thanks, however I tended to think that it is impossible because of  "Oracle Database does not store leading and trailing zeros" as Roberto Hernandez said. I suppose that the way I can do just with help of adding '0' string like this:                                                               
`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('0'||to_char(v_pr)||' --> '||'0'||to_char(v_fin));`

Please let me know if it is а single way

Comment: There is a big difference between what the database "stores" and what it can "display". If you want to **display** a number in a specific format, you must use the `to_char()` function, and give the exact format you want. Perhaps, in your case, that would be `to_char(whatever_numeric_expression, '0.099999')` - this will print a single digit as the integer part, at least one decimal and at most six decimal places. The proper way to learn `to_char()` (and everything else, for that matter) is to find the topic in the documentation and to read about it, not through "examples".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle Database stores numeric data in variable-length format. Each value is stored in scientific notation, with 1 byte used to store the exponent. The database uses up to 20 bytes to store the mantissa, which is the part of a floating-point number that contains its significant digits. **Oracle Database does not store leading and trailing zeros.**

```
SQL> create table prices ( price number(6,3) );

Table created.

SQL> insert into prices values ( 0.293 );

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from prices;

     PRICE
----------
      .293

SQL> alter session set nls_numeric_characters=',.' ;

Session altered.

SQL> select * from prices;

     PRICE
----------
      ,293

SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
--Declare variables
  v_pr number ;
  v_fin number ;
--Declare cursor
CURSOR cur_price IS
  SELECT price FROM prices;
BEGIN
OPEN cur_price;
LOOP      --Simple Loop Start
  FETCH cur_price INTO v_pr;
  v_fin := v_pr * 1.15; --Calculation
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (to_char(v_pr) ||' --> '|| to_char(v_fin));  --Show the result
  EXIT WHEN cur_price%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP; --Simple Loop End
CLOSE cur_price;
END;
/

,293 --> ,33695
,293 --> ,33695
```